# Push specific commits in git

Tags: git, git-push

I have a branch that is composed of several commits. In my particular case, some fixes to the build system, some useful but not important features, and some important features I am developing.

```
* extra commit 5 <wip>
* some commit 4 <useful>
* some commit 3
* feature commit 2 <feature>
* feature commit 1
* main <main>
```

In a branch like this, where I have 5 commits from main, with 3 actual branches (`wip`, `useful` and `feature`), is there any way to specify I want to push to a remote only commit 3 and commit 4 (the subbranch from `feature` to `useful`)?

Comment: You have to reorder your commits with f.e. `git rebase --interactive`. Then you'd checkout the last commit you want to push and push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push a specific refspec (e.g., a branchname) to the remote repository by specifying its name:

```
git push origin useful
```

However, you can't push a specific commit without all the commits before it in the branch (which I think you may have eluded to). If you want to do something like that, you'll have to create a new branch containing only these commits. E.g.:

```
git checkout main # go back to main
git checkout -b newbranch # start a new branch
git cherry-pick <commit 3 hash>..<commit 4 hash>
git push origin newbranch
```

Comment: Fair enough, I was expecting I would need to create the auxiliary branch. Any way to create the auxiliary branch with the cherry-picked commits automatically? Since its all the commits in between two refs, maybe there is something ootb.

Comment: @jjcasmar you can actually specify a range of commits to cherry pick - see my edited answer

Comment: Thanks. I guess I can always do a bash script to automatically perform the creation of the auxiliary branch

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misconception of GIT.
What you modify in a branch will not affect other branches it originated from.

Thus, you may "revert" commits in branch "useful", it wont affect the branch "feature".

Though, in your case, the easiest path would be to create a new branch from main and "cherry-pick" commits 3 and 4 in it.

Another more advanced method would be to perform an "interactive rebase" from "useful" on "main" and "drop" the commits 1 and 2.

Comment: I know how git works. And I know I can drop the commits in feature and get only the ones in useful. However, that affects what is in the branch. Si I have to create an auxiliary branch and remove the feature commits. I was asking if there is an automatic way to do this

Comment: ok, not to my knowledge and it would imply resolving conflicts everytime you push your work

Comment: Yeah, I agree that if the commits I want to extract depend on the previous commits, I would have to solve conflict. But its the best way I can find until some of my work is finally merged into the main branch in the remote

Comment: in this case, one usually have a dedicated branch, which is regularly rebased on the main branch to avoid later complex conflict resolution. You can also make use of the stash to temporarily apply them to your feature branch.